# Why Images.Media.insertImage return null

Tags: android, mediastore, insert-image

I have some code where I run the method MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage (inserting it from a source not a file name), This code saves the image to the MediaStore and returns the uri of the image. I know that when it fails for any reason it will return null instead of a uri. This image has been downloaded multiple times by many people and every once in a while it will return null from this method. I have never had this happen to me so I have no idea what is going on. What are reasons why this could happen? There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576217/most-likely-cause-for-android-provider-mediastore-images-media-insertimage-to-re) with the same issue but the answer is a link to the source code for MediaStore but that link goes to a page saying the link is unavailable. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

After removing my SD card I got this error so I know that could be a reason, I'm not sure but I feel that it would also happen if the card was full. Still just wondering if there could be another reason too.

Answer (score 20):

It seems to happen when you don't have an /sdcard/DCIM/Camera directory on some versions of Android. Creating this directory (and having the permission) solved the problem for me.

Comment: I've had this happen as well after a device reset. Taking a photo with the default Android camera app created the folder, after which I could insert images into it from my code.

Answer (score 9):

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage is actually accessing external storage to save the image.

Some important reminders which might be causing your app to fail:

1. A USB connection will block SD card usage if in Mass Storage mode.
2. There may be other factors that might lead to an SD card being inaccessible, so make sure that you can access the SD card using a file browser first.
3. Make sure that your permissions are correctly configured with android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Posting this here for completeness, as I was getting a null from insertImage, and the cause was *1.*

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue and nothing worked. But finally after 3 hours it worked.

> **Solution:** I found that It works fine until we delete that image from our image gallery. After that It starts returning **null.** But suddenly I tried changing title and description name and it worked like a charm.

> So I've added a **date with the title and description** of bitmap. In case, user deletes bitmap manually from file manager. Still It works.

```
  private fun insertImage(cr: ContentResolver,
        source: Bitmap?,
        title: String,
        description: String
    ): String? {

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-hh.mm.ss.SSS.a", Locale.US)
        val date=sdf.format(Date())

        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title)
        values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title+date)
        values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description+date)
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())

        var url: Uri? = null
        var stringUrl: String? = null    /* value to be returned */

        try {
            url = cr.insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

            if (source != null) {
                val imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url!!)
                try {
                    source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOut)
                } finally {
                    imageOut!!.close()
                }


            } else {
                cr.delete(url!!, null, null)
                url = null
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (url != null) {
                cr.delete(url, null, null)
                url = null
            }
        }

        if (url != null) {
            stringUrl = url.toString()
        }

        return stringUrl
    }
```

> I Implemented to share news bitmap in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayadi.androidbreakdown) and it's working fine.
> Enjoy!

Comment: On android 10, i was facing this issue. and by adding date with title and description work for me. Can you explain the reason? thanks for saving my time @MAyank

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when I was running tests on an emulator with a fresh sdcard image. I was able to solve the problem by creating `/sdcard/Pictures` with

`new File("/sdcard/Pictures").mkdirs();`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have added permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then add this code before calling

> MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (sdcard != null) {
        File mediaDir = new File(sdcard, "DCIM/Camera");
        if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
            mediaDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That second permission is not doing anything - it should be in capital letters `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 1):

When i had such a problem i fixed it with adding permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: That second permission is not doing anything - it should be in capital letters `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 1):

I was executing `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` before getting user permission to **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** which was causing a null path

So make sure user has allowed for permission and then store image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "filename", null);
```

Android 10 needs the actual file name on third paramter of `insertImage()` method.

Comment: Can you tell me the source?