# Sharing a png image in drawable folder

Tags: android, share, social-networking

I am integrating share with the following code for the app.

```
private void socialShare()
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myproject/drawable/appicon");
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sharing myapp");
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share from"));
    }
```

As in the above code, I am trying to put `png image` which is in drawable folder. But the image is unable to be sent. Is that because in setType, it's **image/jpeg**? I can't use jpeg, because it loses transparency. Can some one please suggest me how to share with image?

Here is the code that I use to copy the image from drawable to sdcard:

```
String commonPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyAppFolder"; 
        File direct = new File(commonPath);

        if(!direct.exists())
        {
            if(direct.mkdir()) 
              {
                Log.d("tag","directory created");
               //directory is created;
              }

        }

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.sharingimage);
        OutputStream outStream = null;
           File savingFile = new File(commonPath, "shareImage.png");
           if(!savingFile.exists())
           {
               Log.d("tag","file is created");

           try {
                savingFile.createNewFile();
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(savingFile);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

                Log.d("tag","Saved");

               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

               }

            }
```

Answer (score 18):

I found solution where I should not copy image on sd card. Here it is:

```
    try {
        Uri imageUri = null;
        try {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(),
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fragment_menu_logo), null, null));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        String text = getString(R.string.share_text);
        // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
        Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(mActivity)
                .setType("image/*")
                .setText(text)
                .addStream(imageUri)
                .getIntent();
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.share_google_plus_not_installed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: @RSenApps I forgot to add catching NullPointerException (Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230942/why-images-media-insertimage-return-null explains when it is possible). See updated the answer.

Comment: This makes the drawable loses its transparency, did you find anyway to handle that?

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage is deprecated

Answer (score 11):

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.xxxx);
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/LatestShare.jpg";
OutputStream out = null;
File file=new File(path);
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
path=file.getPath();
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
```

This works for me perfectly, and this will need write permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add this line to android manifest for the write permission.

Comment: You can use getExternalFilesDir(null) to avoid adding the write storage permissions.

Answer (score 10):

You can share using the following method...

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"+R.drawable.ic_launcher);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello, This is test Sharing");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Tried and tested...working for me

Comment: No it doesn't work. It says all items cannot be attached. I tested for fb, google+, gmail, messaging app. Nothing worked.

Comment: Not Working for me, I found other solution check my post below and give it a try

Comment: Works like charm!

Answer (score 6):

First add permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

use Bitmap from res

```
Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.userimage);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    b, "Title", null);
            Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

Tested via bluetooth.

Works like a Charm.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: //open the share sheet
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_14_cold_turkey);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    b, "ColdTurkey", null);

Comment: Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            share.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(share);

Answer (score 2):

No need for a permission. No need to implement a content provider.

This is what you need:

Manifest:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**res/xml/provider_paths.xml**

```
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="cache_root" path="." />
</paths>
```

And the code to use its Intent:

```
@WorkerThread
fun shareDrawable(context: Context, @DrawableRes resourceId: Int, fileName: String): Intent {
    val bitmap = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, resourceId, null)!!.toBitmap()
    val outputFile = File(context.cacheDir, "$fileName.png")
    val outPutStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outPutStream)
    outPutStream.flush()
    outPutStream.close()
    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName, outputFile)
    else
        Uri.fromFile(outputFile))
    shareIntent.type = "image/png"
    return shareIntent
}
```

Comment: Fully working solution. Tested in Android 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly share a `uri` from you apps internal storage (of course the resourses of your app will be always in  the internal storage)

There are two ways of achieving this..

1. Copy your image to external storage then share it from there. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770586/1051147)
2. Write a Content Provider to share image.  For that refer [Create and Share a File from Internal Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188993/1051147)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am unable to make it with the first way.

Comment: did you copy the image into external storage

Comment: No. I am unable to copy the image. It always throws file not found exception. Can you please show me code snippet if you already have it?

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10561536/1051147 And dontforget to add permission to  access SD CARD.

Comment: Make sure that your file names are correct.. and  post the code that you have done..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36440/discussion-between-rick-and-tca)

Comment: the image gets attached but it remains an unreadable file. why?