# Unable to open File For sharing while sharing image file using intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

I have used this code to share image from drawable folder and its opening "Share intent" with list of available sharing possibilities i.e Bluetooth , Gmail ,FB etc.But on Sending file using Bluetooth gives me error "**Unable to Open file for Sharing**"  when trying to share image from Assets folder while getting error "**File not sent**"  when trying to share file from "**drawable folder**".Can someone please hele me how to share image file using Android.........here is the **Manifest File**:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shareima"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shareima.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");
           Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.shareima/drawable/ic_launcher");
            Log.i("imageUri",""+imageUri);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Image"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This [link][1] will help you                 .
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18502670/2011291

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/"+R.drawable.ic_launcher);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello, This is test Sharing");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```

Comment: have applied your changes but getting alert of bluetooth on other device after accepting request its showing me error "File not sent" on sending device

Comment: when i send email via gmail it successfully send but when i download image from email its showing invalid image which indicates there is smoe small problem