# sharing image with whatsapp in android

Tags: android, image, share, whatsapp

I have image in assets folder and need to share it with whatsapp application

I tried this code , it keeps give me sharing failed try again ! what's wrong ?!

```
         Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      share.setType("image/*");
      share.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); 
    //  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///assets/epic/adv.png"))); 
      share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///assets/epic/adv.png"));
      this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share_via"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several problems.

First, `file:///assets/` is not a valid `Uri` on any version of Android. Your own application can refer to its own assets via `file:///android_asset/`.

Second, only you can access your own assets via `file:///android_asset/` -- you cannot pass such a `Uri` to third-party apps. Either copy the file from assets into internal storage and use `FileProvider`, or you can try [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) and try to share the data straight out of `assets/`.

Third, there is no guarantee that `com.whatsapp` exists on the device, or that `com.whatsapp` will support `ACTION_SEND` of `file:///` `Uri` values with a MIME type of `image/*`, and so you may crash with an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Fourth, the user might want to share this image via some other means than WhatsApp. [Please allow the user to share where the *user* wants](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html), by removing the `setPackage()` call from your `Intent`.

Comment: What about a uri of an image in the resources or from a URL ? For resource,  I tried to use Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + imageResId) , but it doesn't seem to work for WhatsApp and for any other app I tried. Looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18502598/878126 , I see it's not possible this way. Is it maybe possible by using FileProvider? Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I do not recommend attempting to share resources that are configuration-dependent (e.g., drawables that vary by density). How `android.resource` handles this is undocumented AFAIK, and it's not like the WhatsApp recipient wants the specific drawable that the sender might send (e.g., a low-res image for an `ldpi` or `mdpi` device). My `StreamProvider` supports raw resources, and you can create your own `ContentProvider` to serve whatever you want. `FileProvider` does not serve resources at all.

Comment: Well I could put the image in the assets folder or the drawable-nodpi if I wish... Are any of those good alternatives? What about url (of somewhere on the Internet) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Unless you need the image in your UI, I'd use `assets`. My `StreamProvider` supports serving from assets, or you can create a `ContentProvider` yourself that handles this. "What about url (of somewhere on the Internet) ?" -- some apps might support this, others might not. `file` had been the safest scheme, up until 7.0. `ACTION_SEND` responders *should* support at least `file` and `content`. Whether they support `https` or `http` or `android.resource` will vary. Unfortunately, we cannot filter on this, so YMMV.

Comment: I see. Can you please share the link to your StreamProvider? Is it easy to import via gradle and start using it? Can you show a tiny snippet of how to use it for assets ? I remember I've handled a similar issue in the past (for APKs), and used my own ContentProvider implementation, so if it will get too complex, I will do it again :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper: My CWAC-Provider library is [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), with instructions and a demo app that, among other things, demonstrates serving assets. You will also see it used in some of my book samples, such as [this one for drag-and-drop](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DragDrop/Permissions).

Comment: ok. thanks. The sample seems to work fine for sending the asset file, but the viewing of pdf doesn't work for some reason. Is there also a way to use it for resources and/or URL ? I've noticed the repo says it's supported, but I don't see it being demonstrated or explained. I will write on the repo about it, because here it's not related... :)

Answer (score 10):

This code for share image via whatsapp worked fine for me .

```
public void shareImageWhatsApp() {

    Bitmap adv = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.adv);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    adv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"temporary_file.jpg"));
    if(isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp",this)){
          share.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); 
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Install Whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: in which version of android did you use this? Seems to my experiment, this code was failed.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
Bitmap imgBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
String imgBitmapPath= MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),imgBitmap,"title",null);
Uri imgBitmapUri=Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath);
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imgBitmapUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"share image using"));
```