# How to create a sharebutton in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, share

i want to create a button and when the button is clicked share an image. I found that i could use this:

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "photo.jpg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

but i dont know where to put it(MainActivity?) i would like to share the image in WhatsApp.

Comment: Add this code to **OnClickListener** function when u click on Button

Comment: @DanhDC i put the OnClickListener but i cant make it work                                                                                                                          public void buttonOnClick(View v){
    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "ic_launcher.png");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
}

Comment: Any have error occur when you click this button. Show your logcat if have error. Please make sure you implement right **OnClickListener** like this : **yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //put share action here
            }
        });**

Comment: @DanhDC Thank you man i made it work. I only have one more question i downloaded the apk to my phone but when i send the image it says that the image is not on the device. What can i do?

Comment: Because, the image **ic_launcher.png** is not visible in your real device, please change it to exist image you have in your phone.

Comment: @DanhDC And what if i pass my PC image to my phone?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but please make sure your image path is correct. It would be better if you pick image from gallery like this http://www.itcuties.com/android/pick-image-from-gallery/ . Then, use this image path to send. Hope it useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set: shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp") to share in whatsapp.

Check this post for more information: [sharing image with whatsapp in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758375/sharing-image-with-whatsapp-in-android)

Comment: Yes but i need to put it in the MainActivity or in the button code?

Comment: In the onclick event for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below link

[Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

[Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

[How to activate “Share” button in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167701/how-to-activate-share-button-in-android-app)