# How to send image from app via messenger?

Tags: java, android, facebook-messenger

I want to send image from my app via messenger. I was looking on Stack Overflow and I found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758375/sharing-image-with-whatsapp-in-android) which works for WhatsApp. When I tried to change "com.whatsapp" to "com.facebook.orca", it stops working. Here is my code:

```
public void shareImageMessenger() {
            Bitmap adv = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.koza);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            adv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "temporary_file_1.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"temporary_file_1.jpg"));
            share.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
        }
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Something went wrong! Please try again later! Or it is just loading and nothing happens.

Comment: Check logcat when it crashes..or try throwing the exception so that we can know what the problem is and then solve it

Comment: Do you have messenger installed on the device you are doing this?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll do that as soon as possible, thank you.

Comment: I cannot find anything in logcat except this: 
018-10-28 15:16:47.909 752-752/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2018-10-28 15:16:47.909 752-752/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2018-10-28 15:16:47.909 752-752/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD

Comment: Would you like a generalized code? where you can select any app you want to share to?

Comment: Anything that works would be nice...

Comment: the image will always in drawable?

Comment: Yes, the image will always be in drawable.

Comment: check my answer. I have tried it and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this:

**Check if permissions are given. Then:**

**Step 1: Create ImageView of the image you want to in the activity and then convert it itno bitmap**

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

//save the image now:
saveImage(bitmap);
//share it
send();
```

**Step 2: Store the image in internal folder:**

```
private static void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    Log.i("Directory", "==" + myDir);
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "Image-test" + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Send the saved image:**

```
public void send() {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/saved_images/Image-test.jpg");
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = myFile.getName().substring(myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        sharingIntent.setType(type);
        sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.fromFile(myFile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Now after sending you can delete the saved image if you don't want it in your storage. Check other link to do that.

Comment: It shows me Toast message with text: pathname("file:////storage/emulated/0/saved_images/Image-test.jpg") for file is exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()...

Comment: Are you using image View? Add it in activity xml

Comment: EDIT:
I solved the problem above by inserting "StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());"

Comment: It works for every single social network, except messenger... I think that there is some bug or something like that. Thank you Arahasya

Comment: It works for messenger also. I've tested it. Try reinstalling messenger and log in

Answer (score 0):

Referring your linked post,You could modify the share intent.

```
 Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 share.setType("image/*");
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///assets/epic/adv.png"));
 this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share_via"));
```

The intent launches the apps which handles Intent.ACTION_SEND. If you want specific app to be respond, make sure you are aware of the package name and  you need set package name       share.setPackage("");