# Sharing a file that is a part of the apk

Tags: android, audio-player

My app plays audio messages that are located in  resource/raw folder. How can I share these audio message via watsapp,e-mail and bluetooth?

Comment: As if they were eMail attachments.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24205753/1064310