# Android : Share drawable resource with other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, drawable

In my activity I have an ImageView. I want ,when user click on it, a dialog opens (like intent dialogs) that show list of apps which can open image than user can choose a app and show the image with that app.

my activity code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.dish);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //here is where I want a dialog that I mentioned show
                }
    });
}// end onCreate()
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502598/878126 . My solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70790973/878126

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a bitmap to an intent.

From what I see you want to share a drawable from your resources. So first you have to convert the drawable to a bitmap. And then You have to save the bitmap to the external memory as a file and then get a uri for that file using Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToTheSavedPicture)) and pass that uri to the intent like this.

```
shareDrawable(this, R.drawable.dish, "myfilename");

public void shareDrawable(Context context,int resourceId,String fileName) {
    try {
        //convert drawable resource to bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId);

        //save bitmap to app cache folder
        File outputFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName + ".png");
        FileOutputStream outPutStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outPutStream);
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();
        outputFile.setReadable(true, false);

        //share file
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        context.startActivity(shareIntent);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this anymore. You get `FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/.../cache/... exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()` . Not only that, but the drawable might not be a bitmap type. Nowadays you can also have a VectorDrawable instead.

Comment: Wrote here a more updated solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70790973/878126

Answer (score -1):

You have to `startActivity` using intent  of type `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`-

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(<your_image_uri>, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Create a chooser by using the following code. You can add it in the part where you say imageview.setonclicklistener(). 
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```