# Send Image via Share : Sends only a strange number and no file extension

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I implemented a share button(code is written in `Kotlin`) which already can send text to whatsapp / email etc.

Now I also want to send an image, but after trying several tutorials, it still displays the same error:

Instead of the picture "image27.png", only an undefined broken file "2131099738" is send.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myapp
...
share_button.setOnClickListener {
        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.type = "image/png"

        val shareImageURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapp/drawable/"+R.drawable.image27)

        val shareSub = "This is for you"
        val shareBody = message 
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareImageURI)
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub)
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share this"))
    }
```

The picture is saved here: `C:\Users\Bine\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\drawable\image27.png`

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try `android.resource://com.example.myapp/drawable/image27` directly

Comment: Yes. Then there is no attachment at all. And when I write it without the file extension '.png' a file with correct name is attached, but you are not able to open it

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is intended. What are you trying to do right now is to share a drawable from you app, but I don't think this will work since every [Android app runs in a Sanbox](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html).

> The Android Application Sandbox, which isolates your app data and code execution from other apps.

However, to better understand your issue, you have to learn about the [`R class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android). In a few words, it is a class generated by the system that holds a reference to everything that is found in the resources directory, including the `drawables` you are using. The important part here is that every reference to a resource will be saved as an `int` variable, hence your `2131099738` appears there when you try to use `R.drawable.image27.png` (Note that if you make any changes to resources, there is a huge chance that this number will change).

To solve the problem, you have two approaches:

1. store the file in the [external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html);
2. use a [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) to access the file.

Comment: ok great. I understand. I already found `ContentResolver.openInputStream(shareImageURI)` but it does not work like that in Kotlin. Do you know how to use this?

Comment: Well, as I already said, you can't share a drawable because of the Sandbox (it is only visible to you app). You can have a look here to see a few ways on how you can share it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9TunRURWNU), but you have to store the file in the external storage.  An alternative would ve something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36212192/3734172, but this approach is more of a "hack" than an actual solution. The proper way to do it is to save it on external storage and then use the path to share it.