# how to share image stored in resource folder in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to share GIF image that is stored in resource folder, can I share that GIF Directly or in any other

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.myproject/drawable/xyz.gif");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sharing myapp");
shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share from"));
```

use above code but no any app found in chooser to open gif, but in my default photo gallery i can open that gif and also share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing a png image in drawable folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502598/sharing-a-png-image-in-drawable-folder)

Comment: already try that code but not working

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/24205753/3166697?

Comment: yes, also try that but not working