# How to share image of app

Tags: android

I have picture in drawable and I want to share that one image.

Following is my code,

```
 btnic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.defaultpicture);
            Intent ppp = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            ppp.setType("image/png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    b, "defaultpicture", null);
            Uri uri =  Uri.parse(path);
            ppp.putExtras(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); **i am getting error here**
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ppp, "Send picture"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502598/sharing-a-png-image-in-drawable-folder

Comment: @Ravi Kilnake just make sure the image you pass in intent should have to be of particular size . Use a bigger image other than `ic_launcher` only for sharing .

Comment: kindly see the new edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` takes value as `Local` path of file on storage not on resource (Not a resource ID).
 So you need to first save the image as file in storage then pass the url to sharing Intent .
First decode resource.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
```

Save it to specific location on storage and use this file path as value in intent. you can save it as below or in some other way.

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
        b, "myFile", null);
```

Comment: Error:(55, 20) error: no suitable method found for putExtras(String,Uri)
method Intent.putExtras(Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Intent.putExtras(Bundle) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length).. i am confused

Answer (score 0):

```
                final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "yourimage.jpg");
                Log.d("TAG", "onClick: "+photoFile);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

for more about [Sharing Content with Intents](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents)

Comment: this gives an error on share1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri1);

Comment: the error remains. "cannot resolve method'putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri2)"

Comment: i will check it wait

Comment: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=org.chromium.components.sync.notifier.ACTION_REGISTER_TYPES cmp=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.invalidation.ChromeInvalidationClientService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7860c3 u0a45 LAST bg:+12m57s541ms idle procs:2 seq(15,15,15)}  :(

Comment: can i get your email please?

Comment: for what purpose?