# android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage returns null

Tags: android

I have following code:

```
Uri u_img = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
getContentResolver(),f.getAbsolutePath(), null, null));
```

but `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` returns null on Galaxy S6 6.0.1.

I have tried following possible solutions but no luck:

> 1. Checking permission of Writing to External Storage -> OK
> 2. Try to do the checking of directory is there or not by f.exists() and it returns true

What could be another reason?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_external_storage" />

Comment: I thought writing should also include the read `Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission.`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230942/why-images-media-insertimage-return-null

Comment: Please see my 2nd solution above..

Answer (score 0):

```
public  void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are encountering this problem in android Marshmallow, as you said on Galaxy S6 6.0.1.
This is because of permissions.you need to request for write permission as `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` try to write on sd card.
Open a Dialog using the code below:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);
```

Also this link can help you with permission in android 6(Marshmallow)
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html